# Find only specific key from mongodb using pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have written this code and I want to check only for a key named `Virtual_Machines`. I have data in the following form. I only want to check if `Virtual_Machines` is there then don't upload data again.

```
  {
          "Virtual_Machines": {
               "Debian": {
                    "VM_Name": "Debian",
                    "VM_Location": "eastus",
                    "VM_Disk_Name": "Debian_OsDisk_1_b890f5f5c42647549c881c0706b85201",
                    "VM_Publisher_Info": {
                         "publisher": "debian",
                         "offer": "debian-11",
                         "sku": "11-gen2",
                         "version": "latest"
                    },
                    "Vm_Disk_Type": "Standard_D2s_v3",
                    "VM_Encryption": null
               },
               "Ubuntu": {
                    "VM_Name": "Ubuntu",
                    "VM_Location": "eastus",
                    "VM_Disk_Name": "Ubuntu_disk1_0610e0fde49b481490ef0a069a03b460",
                    "VM_Publisher_Info": {
                         "publisher": "canonical",
                         "offer": "0001-com-ubuntu-server-focal",
                         "sku": "20_04-lts-gen2",
                         "version": "latest"
                    },
                    "Vm_Disk_Type": "Standard_D2s_v3",
                    "VM_Encryption": null
               }
          }
     },
```

My code is but it is giving output as `None`.

```
db = client['Audit']
vms = db['virtual_machine']
vm = json.dumps(vm)
vmachine = vms.find_one({"Virtual_Machine"},{'_id':0})    

print(vmachine)
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please describe what exactly you are looking to match and what your expected document looks like.

Comment: @BellyBuster I have data in the form of `JSON` and I want to check if that data is already present in MongoDB so that I do not upload it again. so I want to check by comparing to `Virtual Machines` which is a `key` here not a value so How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter in `find_one()` must be a `dict`. You are getting your error because you are passing `{"Virtual_Machine"}` which python interprets as a `set` https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set

If you want to check that a key exists or not, regardless of its value, use the `$exists` operator. https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/

```
vms.find_one({'Virtual_Machines': {'$exists': True}}, {'_id':0})
```